# Less driven Toyota Corolla 2007 Maintenance

Tags: maintenance

I have this 15 year old car, mileage today is 37,000. I am very confused about when to change oil and do all the other recommended maintenance. I plan to drive it at about the same rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your owners manual, it will give you recommended service intervals.  For most of them it's X months or Y miles/km.

For those that are miles/km only you can defer them if you like.

I'm not familiar with your specific model but the most common oil change spec is 3 months or 3000 miles whichever comes first.  So for a little-driven vehicle, you will almost always hit the months before the miles.

Comment: Thanks, I did that when I bought the car, but the oil change shop said your oil looks very fine, come back after 6 months. This kept happening, so I have changed oil may be 6-7 times in 37,000 miles. I hope this is OK, but I am not sure.

Comment: It's up to you to decide whether to follow the manufacturer's recommended intervals or listen to someone who works at an oil change shop.  But I do know that you cannot tell oil's condition visually.  Oil in a car that sits a lot builds up moisture that accelerates corrosion inside the engine.

Comment: Agree with @jwh20. It is cheaper to change the oil as outlined in the owners manual versus buying a new engine.